# Render only Nodes that Change

Tags: compositing-nodes

When compositing with Blender, oftentimes I'll end up with a large node graph, with most of the nodes not changing at all.  However, whenever I add another node, even if it's not connected to the rest of the nodes, or if I just add a Reroute pin, blender rerenders the whole graph.  This seems like a waste of time to me, since only the nodes downstream of any changes need to run again.

Is there a way to make Blender not rerender the entire graph every time a change is made in the node editor, preferably just rendering the nodes downstream of the change?

Comment: you could just save the part you don't want to change as an image and continue from an image node, it's a bit frustrating to do, but it definitely saves time.